# jQuery Typing effect stop loop

Tags: jquery

I am trying to stop the loop at the last word "**three**" but it keeps looping and I can't figure it out how. Any solutions? thanks!

```
/*  
Type animation
*/

const words = ["one", "two" , "three"];
let i = 0;
let timer;

function typingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopTyping = function() {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML += word.shift();
        } else {
            deletingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopTyping, 300);
    };
    loopTyping();
};

function deletingEffect() {
    let word = words[i].split("");
    var loopDeleting = function() {
        if (word.length > 0) {
            word.pop();
            document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word.join("");
        } else {
            if (words.length > (i + 1)) {
                i++;
            } else {
                i = 0;
            };
            typingEffect();
            return false;
        };
        timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 10);
    };
    loopDeleting();
};

typingEffect();
```

Here's the fiddle code: https://jsfiddle.net/al1225/w4rd65yx/

tried to debug the code but no luck on how to stop the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put  `return false` inside `else` condition when `i = 0` on `deletingEffect()` function.

Working example:

```js
/*  
Type animation
*/

const words = ["one", "two", "three"];
let i = 0;
let timer;
let flag = 0;

function typingEffect() {
  let word = words[i].split("");
  var loopTyping = function() {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      document.getElementById('word').innerHTML += word.shift();
    } else {
      flag++
      if (flag < 3) {
        deletingEffect();
      }
      return false;
    };
    timer = setTimeout(loopTyping, 300);
  };
  loopTyping();


};

function deletingEffect() {
  let word = words[i].split("");
  var loopDeleting = function() {
    if (word.length > 0) {
      word.pop();
      document.getElementById('word').innerHTML = word.join("");
    } else {
      if (words.length > (i + 1)) {
        i++;
      } else {
        i = 0;
        return false;
      };
      typingEffect();
      return false;
    };
    timer = setTimeout(loopDeleting, 10);
  };
  loopDeleting();
};

typingEffect();
```

```html
<h1 class="header-sub-title" id="word"></h1>
<h1 class="header-sub-title blink">|</h1>
```

Comment: Great thanks! Another question, how can I stop the animation at "three" without it disappearing? So after the loop, it'll just display the "three" as the last frame.

Comment: @HELLBORN Set flag for that, see updated answer.